# How do I load a scene in Unity for the current client, but not any other client?

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking, scenemanager

I'm currently using NetworkManager.Singleton.SceneManager.LoadScene using the Netcode package, but it loads the new scene for both the current player and any other connected clients. I want it to only load for the current player, such that for the current player the other clients player prefabs are destroyed, but not the current player's and vice versa for the other clients. That way I can have multiple rooms, and when you enter the same room as someone else you can see them. How would I do this?

The code looks something like this and is placed on the player prefab

```
public class MultiplayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
   void Update(){
      if (Input.GetButton("Jump")) //Transform
      {
            NetworkManager.Singleton.SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNames[1], LoadSceneMode.Single);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used NetworkManager, but it sounds like you should disconnect from the players in the current room before entering a new room with new players.